# rtl8812ae Wifi Connection Instability in Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, wifi, networkmanager, wpa-supplicant, realtek

I just added a D-Link DWA-582 PCI-e WiFi adapter using the Realtek RTL8812AE chipset. I confirmed the support for the chipset at https://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x#rtl8821ae . I have installed the Realtek firmware using `apt-get install firmware-realtek` and confirmed that it is in use using `modprobe rtl8821ae`When I connect to the wireless access point I can maintain a connection for ~6 seconds. I usually am connected just long enough to establish a dhcp lease and then the network disconnects again. I have not been very successful in finding much information on how to diagnose/resolve this issue despite several hours of reading forum posts and trying suggestions.

I have tried replacing Network Manager with wicd without any change or improvement.

I am not really sure what the best information is for diagnosing this issue, so I have posted something to get started, and I hope all you guru's will want more and/or have some ideas and solutions!

Wireless Info tool output http://pastebin.com/Dd7igCqb

```
root@pink-fluffy-unicorn:~# uname -v
#1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u3 (2016-01-17)
```

```
root@pink-fluffy-unicorn:~# lspci | grep Network
04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

```
root@pink-fluffy-unicorn:~# apt-get install firmware-realtek
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
firmware-realtek is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
root@pink-fluffy-unicorn:~# modprobe rtl8821ae
root@pink-fluffy-unicorn:~#
```

```
root@pink-fluffy-unicorn:~# iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"WLAN-927602"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 94:4A:0C:DF:A5:BB   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

`journalctl -u NetworkManager`
http://pastebin.com/4zzbMxcC

`journalctl -u wpa_supplicant`
http://pastebin.com/1MPx03fj

`journalctl -k`
http://pastebin.com/JAvM9gDy

## Updates:

Following the suggestion from GAD3R I tried to disable power management using `iwconfig` with the following results:

```
root@pink-fluffy-unicorn:~# iwconfig wlan0 power off
Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.
```

I then enabled power management using `modprobe rtl8821ae swlps=1` to power management and then ran `iwconfig wlan0 power off` again, which executed without error. I then confirmed that power management was disabled using `iwconfig wlan0` and monitored the output from `journalctl -f`. There did not appear to be any change from the altered configuration (I also tried `iwconfig wlan0 power on` to see if there was any change/improvement but it did not appear to have any significant impact)

Answer (score 1):

This what worked in linux for this awful card:

WIFI DRIVER - Wireless AC1200 Dual Band PCI Express Adapter rtl8812ae DWA‑582

```
sudo pacman -S linux419-headers
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git 
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8821ae
```

Now on linux system my wifi works better then in windows 10, in windows I have random disconnects which I don't have on linux, or at least much less disconnects. 
Really hate this card, it killed a lot of my time and nerve cells

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable power management

```
iwconfig wlan0 power off
```